# How to fetch byte array image from api in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing app with React frontend and ASP.NET Core Web API backend. I want to send some image through `GET` request from API:

```
[Route("getimage")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetImage()
{
    var objectWithImage = db.SomeTable.SingleOrDefault();

    byte[] image = objectWithImage.SomeImage;

    return Ok(image);
}
```

As you can see it's pretty simple method that gets image I want from database and sends it to site. The image is saved as `byte` array.

Now in front I'm trying to fetch this image and display it in `<img src={this.state.image}>`

```
class SomeClass extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props = props;
        this.state = {
            image: null,
        }
    }

async getImage() {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/controller/getimage")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        this.setState({
           image: data

       })
   })
   console.log(this.state.image)
}
```

Obviously it doesn't work, the first `console.log` is displaying binary data normally, the second log after I `setState` is saying that `image` is `null`.

How to fetch this `byte[]` with image properly and display it on page? I tried to look through some other similar threads but no fix seems to work. I'm quite new to react any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert byte array to image by concating `"data:image/png;base64," + data;`
you can say `this.setState({image: "data:image/png;base64," + data;})`

```
    async getImage() {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/controller/getimage")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        this.setState({
           image: data

       })
   })
   console.log(this.state.image) // *1
}
```

*1 line is print null because this happens before `this.setState`. And `this.setState` will trigger the render function then your image will show up.

Hope it will help :)